# finding solution to initial value problem

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Find a particular solution to the initial value problem
$$
x'(t)=Ax(t), ~~\text{ where }~~ A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1 \\ 0&\pi&0 \\ 1&0&1\end{bmatrix}
​$$
and
$$
x(\pi/2) =\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}
$$

How would i solve this?

Comment: 1) Do you know the exponential of a matrix ? 2) Have you seen that, up to a permutation, you matrix is block-diagonal ?

Comment: @JeanMarie 1) yes 2) i have not observed this because idk why it's useful for this question

Comment: You get $(x_1+ix_3)'=(1+i)(x_1+ix_3)$ separately from $x_2'=\pi x_2$.

Comment: It is useful because in this way the exponential is immediate (as @Ben Grossmann has done)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$. Note that it suffices to separately solve the following IVPs:
$$
\pmatrix{x_1'\\x_3'} = \pmatrix{1 & -1\\1&1} \pmatrix{x_1\\x_3}, \quad \pmatrix{x_1(\pi/2)\\ x_3(\pi/2)} = \pmatrix{1\\3}
$$
and
$$
x_2' = \pi x_2, \quad x_2(\pi/2) = 2.
$$